# Cosine Distance does't work with SparseDataFrame Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, cosine-similarity

May someone explain to me Why this one works and the other one isn't? When I change to SparseDataFrame

```
data = pd.read_csv('/.../.csv').astype(float)

data_germany = data.drop('user', 1)

data_ibs = pd.DataFrame(index=data_germany.columns,columns=data_germany.columns)

for i in tqdm(range(0,len(data_ibs.columns))) :
    # Loop through the columns for each column
    for j in range(0,len(data_ibs.columns)) :
      # Fill in placeholder with cosine similarities
      data_ibs.iloc[i,j] = 1-cosine(data_germany.iloc[:,i],data_germany.iloc[:,j])

#######################################################

data = pd.read_csv('/.../.csv').astype(float)**.to_sparse()**

data_germany = data.drop('user', 1)

data_ibs = pd.**Sparse**DataFrame(index=data_germany.columns,columns=data_germany.columns)

for i in tqdm(range(0,len(data_ibs.columns))) :
    # Loop through the columns for each column
    for j in range(0,len(data_ibs.columns)) :
      # Fill in placeholder with cosine similarities
      data_ibs.iloc[i,j] = 1-cosine(data_germany.iloc[:,i],data_germany.iloc[:,j])
```

It counts cosine distance correctly till the moment when I try to assign the numbers to the dataframe

How is it possible??

Thanks for helping in advance

Comment: `pd.**Sparse**DataFrame`? Did you mean `pd.SparseDataFrame`? The syntax you have just isn't valid Python, so that might be why it isn't working.

Comment: I just tried to highlight the place what I added for comparison_) Thought it worked like in MS Word (cmd + b)

Comment: It does, but it surrounds the text with the `**` symbols. This will render normal text bold, but not "code formatted" text